# HAProxy + uwsgi all connection "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: haproxy, uwsgi

I've a problem with UWSGI + HAProxy.
for all the connections that get closed, i see this log in uwsgi file `[uwsgi-http key:  client_addr: 192.168.173.250 client_port: 57002] hr_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 917]`

i can easily reproduce it with this

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     requests.get('http://my-ha-url')
...
<Response [200]>
..
<Response [200]>
```

i see this

```
[uwsgi-http key:  client_addr: 192.168.173.250 client_port: 35534] hr_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 917]
...
[uwsgi-http key:  client_addr: 192.168.173.250 client_port: 59134] hr_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 917
```

**BUT If i call directly without passing trough HA (calling the endpoing) there's no log in uwsgi.**

Has anyone idea of what can be?
is HA persisting the connection and at some point cutting it off?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the config of uwsgi we had
`http-keepalive = 650` and that was causing the problem.

Comment: apparently the problem still exists for some connections, this time with a key `[uwsgi-http key: <mywebsite> client_addr: 192.168.172.251 client_port: 41975] hr_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 917]`